# Very long camel redelivery policy

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-classic

I am using Camel and I have a business problem. We consume order messages from an activemq queue. The first thing we do is check in our DB to see if the customer exists. If the customer doesn't exist then a support team needs to populate the customer in a different system. Sometimes this can take a 10 hours or even the following day.

My question is how to handle this. It seems to me at a high level I can dequeue these messages, store them in our DB and re-run them at intervals (a custom coded solution) or I could note the error in our DB and then return them back to the activemq queue with a long redelivery policy and expiration, say redeliver every 2 hours for 48 hours.

This would save a lot of code but my question is if approach 2 is a sound approach or could lead to resource issues or problems with not knowing where messages are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common scenario. If you want insight into how the jobs are progressing, then it's best to use a database for this.

Your queue consumption should be really simple: consume the message, check if the customer exists; if so process, otherwise write a record in a TODO table.

Set up a separate route to run on a timer - every X minutes. It should pull out the TODO records, and for each record check if the customer exists; if so process, otherwise update the record with the current timestamp (the last time the record was retried).

This allows you to have a clear view of the state of the system, that you can then integrate into a console to see what the state of the outstanding jobs is.

There are a couple of downsides with your Option 2:

- you're relying on the ActiveMQ scheduler, which uses a KahaDB variant sitting alongside your regular store, and may not be compatible with your H/A setup (you need a shared file system)
- you can't see the messages themselves without scanning through the queue, which is an antipattern - using a queue as a database - you may as well use a database, especially if you can anticipate needing to ever selectively remove a particular message.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, that confirmed what I was thinking.